# Codeigniter 4 validation always return false with getJSON

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, postman, codeigniter-4

I'm using ci4 to validate the json raw sent from postman, but i always get false result please help me check it

```
        public function create(){
            
            helper(['form', 'url']);

            $_POST = $this->request->getJSON(true);
            // $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); try not working

            $rules = [
                "product_name" => [
                    'rules' => 'required',
                    'errors' => [
                        'required' => 'Product name is required!'
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            if($this->validate($rules)){
                echo true;
            }
            else{
                echo false; // always return false
            }
            die;
        }

        // postman json: { "product_name": "Iphone 12 pro max" }
```

Comment: So whats the var_dump() you get for $_POST?

Comment: hi Tim, is an array: 
array(1) {
["product_name"]=>
string(17) "Iphone 12 pro max"
}

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/controllers.html)

> **The method accepts an array of rules in the first parameter**, and in
> the **optional second parameter, an array of custom error messages** to
> display if the items are not valid.

You are passing both to `validate()` in a single array as the first parameter, which of course is not being interpreted correctly as just a ruleset. You need to split the rules and errors into separate arrays:

```
$rules = ["product_name" => 'required'];
$errors = ["product_name" => ['required' => "Product name is required!"]];
if (!$this->validate($rules, $errors)){...
```